# Ubuntu is installed on my 250G ssd, but i want to install everything else on my 2TR Hardrive

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, hard-drive, ssd, drive

So is it possible? what is the simplest way to do this at this point, booth using the App store but also when installing pacakes through the terminal? thanks for the help, also i am on ubuntu 19.10

Comment: what exactly do you want to install on the 2tr drive?

Comment: have you tried making simplink of /home on 2tr drive that's most things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some apps install under /home . Some apps don't.

The first thing, therefore, is to put /home on that HDD.

Directories under /bin and /usr/bin are where some apps install into, so put that on the HDD as well.